# What happens if the namespace declaration (xmlns) goes off?

Tags: c#, wpf

**Note before reading**: This is a general question, that I chose to ask about a specific extension, but the answer should be the same... I guess.

I've started to implement localization in my project, and I'm using the `WPF Localization Extension` lib, but I have a few questions:

In order for the lib to work, it's is required to add this definition to every xaml page:
`xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com"`

And I have 2 questions regarding that:
 1. What if the URL goes off, for some unknown reason? Will my application just lose all of the extension's functionality? Is there an option to someone avoid using the url, and instead using some local file or something...?
 2. I'm using calibrun.micro, and obviously my application has a few pages, and they're all embedded within the `ShellView.xaml` page through a `ContentControl`. Is there an option to write the namespace declarations (xmlns:lex, etc... - see code below) in just the shellview and have it affect all of the other pages automatically? It sounds really inefficient to have to specify the declarations in each single xaml page.

**Extra Info:**

Extension page: http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/
Namespace declarations/definitions:

```
    xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com"
    lex:LocalizeDictionary.DesignCulture="en"
    lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="WpfApplication3"
    lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="Strings"
```

Comment: For number 2, Resharper (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) deals with this by automatically adding the namespace for objects in XAML when you press ALT+Enter, saves me quite a bit of time. Might be worth downloading a trial copy - the licenses aren't too expensive either

Comment: @charleh This is a ReSharper Feature I actually dislike a LOT. Because it adds a `clr-namespace` type of reference, when it should actually be adding the relevant `xmlns` type of reference. Third parties (such as DevExpress or Infragistics) usually have MANY CLR namespaces mapped to a single `xmlns`, so R#'s feature is bad in this case.

Comment: Yes I agree, there have been times when I've had xmlns called `controls1`, `controls2`, `controls3` because of mapping to say Telerik's UC suite - but it's a saver for components in your own solution (unless you provide a consolidated ns). I still find it useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - That url is only symbolic. It doesn't point to an actual internet address. it could be "http://whatever.com" and it would still work as long as it is exactly the same as the xml namespace defined in the [`XmlnsDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx) in the assembly you're referring to.
To be clear, it's just a name (which just happens to have an internet-like format), not a website address.

2 - No, there's no way to declare a project-wide `xmlns`. That's one of the loudest complains we have to microsoft, but they abandoned WPF in favor or WinRT so I'm not hoping for a fix.

Comment: They're defined in this file:  http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WPFLocalizeExtension/WPFLocalizeExtension/Engine/LocalizeDictionary.cs  Oddly, the URLs in code are different than what the OP is using...

Comment: I'm using what is written in the documentation... http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Preparing%20the%20XAML%20code&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: And @HighCore, thanks! That's great as long as it won't just stop working one day. As for 2... well, at least I know I'm not the only one with that 'problem'. :/